# Read/write to Windows registry using Java

Tags: java, registry

How is it possible to read/write to the Windows registry using Java?

Comment: I'd say the easiest way is using `com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper`

Comment: @Jire That is better than the accepted solution in every way except that you need to include the "deploy.jar" from your java install in the project--it's not included automatically.  It also suffers from the same big issue--it can't handle anything but strings (not even multi-strings).  You could add it as a new answer with some example uses.  If you don't have a high enough rep to post to this question, let me know and I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 343):

I know this question is old, but it is the first search result on google to "java read/write to registry".  Recently I found this amazing piece of code which:

- Can read/write to ANY part of the registry.
- DOES NOT USE JNI.
- DOES NOT USE ANY 3rd PARTY/EXTERNAL APPLICATIONS TO WORK.
- DOES NOT USE THE WINDOWS API (directly)

This is pure, Java code.

It uses reflection to work, by actually accessing the private methods in the `java.util.prefs.Preferences` class. The internals of this class are complicated, but the class itself is very easy to use.

For example, the following code obtains the exact windows distribution **from the registry**:

```
String value = WinRegistry.readString (
    WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                             //HKEY
   "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion",           //Key
   "ProductName");                                              //ValueName
    System.out.println("Windows Distribution = " + value);
```

Here is the original class. Just copy paste it and it should work:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {
  public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
  public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
  public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
  public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
  public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

  private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
  private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
  private static final Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
  private static final Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
  private static final Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
  private static final Method regOpenKey;
  private static final Method regCloseKey;
  private static final Method regQueryValueEx;
  private static final Method regEnumValue;
  private static final Method regQueryInfoKey;
  private static final Method regEnumKeyEx;
  private static final Method regCreateKeyEx;
  private static final Method regSetValueEx;
  private static final Method regDeleteKey;
  private static final Method regDeleteValue;

  static {
    try {
      regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, int.class });
      regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
      regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",
          new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
      regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue",
          new Class[] { int.class, int.class, int.class });
      regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1",
          new Class[] { int.class });
      regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class, int.class,  
              int.class });  
      regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
      regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);  
      regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class, byte[].class });  
      regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod(  
          "WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[] { int.class,  
              byte[].class });  
      regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  private WinRegistry() {  }

  /**
   * Read a value from key and value name
   * @param hkey   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @return the value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key 
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringValues(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringValues(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read the value name(s) from a given key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @return the value name(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int [] ret;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
    if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Write a value in a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void writeStringValue
    (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete a given key
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * delete a value from a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
    }
  }

  // =====================

  private static int deleteValue
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return handles[1];  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
    }
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) 
          })).intValue();
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return rc;
  }

  private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) })).intValue();
    return rc;  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
  }

  private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null; 
    }
    byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) });
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
  }

  private static Map<String,String> readStringValues
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count = info[0]; // count  
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
      String value = readString(hkey, key, new String(name));
      results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static List<String> readStringSubKeys
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) 
        });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });

    int count  = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by Petrucio
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer
            (handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
          });
      results.add(new String(name).trim());
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  private static int [] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    return  (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root,
        new Object[] { new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key) });
  }

  private static void writeStringValue 
    (Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });

    regSetValueEx.invoke(root,  
        new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value) 
          }); 
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
  }

  // utility
  private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
    }
    result[str.length()] = 0;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Original Author: Apache.

Library Source: https://github.com/apache/npanday/tree/trunk/components/dotnet-registry/src/main/java/npanday/registry

Comment: How to use this class to read HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT? As Windows documentations says, the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes. So reading one of this keys is not an option.

Comment: This code has a minor bug; readStringSubKeys to enumerate the subkeys of a registry key doesn't work. Replace "int count = info[2]; // count  " in the private readStringSubKeys function with "int count = info[0]; // count", and that will fix it. The correct value can be seen in the reflected WindowsPreferences.SUBKEYS_NUMBER field.

Comment: Wow... two questions, what kind of crazy brain gave birth to this master piece, and how hard will Java engineer smash their head on the wall when they read this ?

Comment: Code with "inspired by" links can be found at Réal Gagnon's site www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0630.html ?

Comment: So basically, any java program can read/write/delete anything from the registry? That's kinda scary...

Comment: @nbarraille *any java program with adequate access. Also, this does not seem to work on some computers. I'm not sure if it works at all on 1.7 either. This hack is old, 2008, and you can achieve the same thing with JNA. Is it scary that every program you run can read/write to the registry?

Comment: *JAW DROP*, wow! wish I could upvote this more than once. 
I used this code so successfully query Keys stored in a Win7 Virtualized registry which neither the Regedit nor the Reg CLI tools could provide.

Comment: I am trying to write a new variable at specific path, but it is not able to create that variable. My code is    WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\COMPANYNAME\\VOLUME-I", "JOB", "YES");

Comment: How do I get this to read a dword? His sample works just fine for a string, but I need to get an actual value out to read now. Just comes out as null.

Comment: Here's another quite similar class to do this: http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/reading-windows-registry-java-without-jni

Comment: Does anyone know if my program would need administrator privileges to run this?

Comment: It depends what keys your write to.

Comment: Compiled by Oracle's 1.7.0_05 to .class, caused Microsoft Security Essentials (antivirus) to spit the dummy. It referred to http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?name=Exploit%3aJava%2fCVE-2012-4681&threatid=2147664168 a

Comment: where is this code from? is it yours? What's the license? public domain?

Comment: **This is licensed under the Apache license** given some [google searching](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/npanday/trunk/components/dotnet-registry/src/main/java/npanday/registry/impl/WinRegistry.java).

Comment: Worked for me, and I guess plenty of people will find this snippet too in the future. But please, note at the top of the answer if you fix bugs in it, etc.

Comment: This is very nasty - it involves invoking non-public methods through reflection.  In other words, you are going outside the Preferences contract as described in the Javadocs, and this code may break any time Oracle push out a new update.

Comment: @Qix Are you sure that the author didn't get that class from here? As far as I can tell, the commit date was *after* this was posted. I originally had found this on a forum a long time ago.

Comment: Anyone has idea about how to write a dword into registry by using these methods?

Comment: This code has a bug. In the method 'readStringValues' the line 'int count = info[0];' should be replaced with 'int count = info[2];' and the line 'int maxlen = info[3];' should be replaced with 'int maxlen = info[4];'

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when writing string value?? Very confusing API

Comment: @David this outputs the version of windows right? What if I wanted to display or shall I say "ëxport" the entire path of where my current version can be found how will I do that?

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to store values using the readStringValues(int String, String key) method, when trying to load all of the values and data into a map

Comment: @David I am trying to write a new variable at specific path, but it is not able to create that variable. My code is String value = WinRegistry.readString(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, // HKEY
     "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Sesseion Manager\\Environment", // Key
     "ComSpec");

Comment: It seems JNA could be used as well: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-read-write-windows-registry-using-jna.html

Comment: @all I'm trying to get java "Options" registry value of tomcat service and couldn't  get that but when I try to retrieve "Classpath" registry value I can get easily. In other words few of the registry value is not retrieving. 
Please help me, is there any permission issue or something else which I'm missing.

Comment: Why this answer has too many upvotes and negative comments? Doesn't this trick work?

Comment: Note that in private function readStringValues, remember to check the name is null before adding into map (NPE), the same is applied to readStringSubKeys()

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen It works, I just implemented it on Java 8.  It has a lot of limitations (It seems to only work with Strings).  I haven't bothered to look at the Preferences class that it uses but I'm pretty sure it's nothing but a little JNI magic in there.  If you aren't just hacking out a solution you probably want to go for a JNI solution or some Apache class instead (I'm guessing there is an Apache class for this, there is for everything else, right?)

Comment: Just went to look at the source code for the preferences class and it really is just a little JNI help and some retry logic, if you want more control or you think using internal classes is too dangerous, you could start with the source code here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/prefs/WindowsPreferences.java.html and trim it down to what you want--This is obviously how this code was created--it looks a lot like the code in WindowsPreferences itself.

Comment: Thanks, @BillK for sharing your findings. I would further look into this solution and update accordingly.

Comment: @David I am able to add key and string values using this API. But my concern is to edit the "default" property in "command". I am not able to achieve this. can you help me?

Comment: This code might no longer work in `Java 9` because it generates the following warning: `An illegal reflective access operation has occurred`

Comment: I was unable to read the key "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled"=dword:00000001

Comment: Here are hex codes of all root HKEYS http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/ticket/820

Comment: With Java 11 an 12 this doesn't seem to work, as the first argument for ALL the methods has to be changed from int to long. userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",
          new Class[] { long.class, byte[].class, int.class });

Comment: Concerning methods invocations : they are all static methods and so it is useless to invoke them with `systemRoot` or `userRoot`, `null` is sufficient.

Comment: Please add in the post, that this can only read/write (Tree Path) Keys and String values, not binary/DWORD/QWORD values.

Answer (score 136):

You don't actually need a 3rd party package. Windows has a reg utility for all registry operations. To get the command format, go to the DOS propmt and type:

```
reg /?
```

You can invoke *reg* through the Runtime class:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg <your parameters here>");
```

Editing keys and adding new ones is straightforward using the command above. To read the registry, you need to get *reg*'s output, and it's a little tricky. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;

/**
 * @author Oleg Ryaboy, based on work by Miguel Enriquez 
 */
public class WindowsReqistry {

    /**
     * 
     * @param location path in the registry
     * @param key registry key
     * @return registry value or null if not found
     */
    public static final String readRegistry(String location, String key){
        try {
            // Run reg query, then read output with StreamReader (internal class)
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + 
                    '"'+ location + "\" /v " + key);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            reader.start();
            process.waitFor();
            reader.join();
            String output = reader.getResult();

            // Output has the following format:
            // \n<Version information>\n\n<key>\t<registry type>\t<value>
            if( ! output.contains("\t")){
                    return null;
            }

            // Parse out the value
            String[] parsed = output.split("\t");
            return parsed[parsed.length-1];
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    static class StreamReader extends Thread {
        private InputStream is;
        private StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();

        public StreamReader(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
                    sw.write(c);
            }
            catch (IOException e) { 
        }
        }

        public String getResult() {
            return sw.toString();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Sample usage
        String value = WindowsReqistry.readRegistry("HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\" 
                 + "Explorer\\Shell Folders", "Personal");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Oleg, that was really useful, thanks! Note that the readRegistry method can add a second StreamReader if you want to read the output of process.getErrorStream(). P.S. there's an extra semicolon in "new StringWriter();;".

Comment: This code works great! However, there is a problem with your parsing. On my Windows 7 setup there are no tab characters.  The parsing code should be a little more robust.  I've changed it in my implementation to look for the key to make sure it has output.  I then use a regular expression to split on the whitespace and get the last string.  That should always be the value for the key.

Comment: can anyone please explain why the reading has been made multithreaded here ?

Comment: This works nicely except when the key has spaces in it.  To guard against that it should be             Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + 
                    '"'+ location + "\" /v \"" + key + "\"");

Comment: Wish I'd seen Mike G's comment on Sept 22, would have saved me some trouble.  Yes, you can't depend on Tab and I was hoping to learn whether this was a Windows 7 thing.  It is.  But you can't really split on whitespace either since keys or values may have them.  My solution, I think, will be to search for the expected type ("REG_BINARY", etc.) and then the value will be after the whitespace after that.

Comment: What about writing the registry key?

Comment: I do not recommend doing this. I have a command which calls "reg query HKLM/Software/Some/Path" and it fails to look under HKLM and instead calls HKCU. There is no obvious reason for this behaviour, it just does it. It could be permissions related, or something, but whatever the reason reg.exe is broken when called this way.

Comment: In answer to my own comment the issue has to do with this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252297/why-is-regopenkeyex-returning-error-code-2-on-vista-64bit). Basically reg.exe is 64-bit whereas JVM may be 32-bit so they could be looking in different places for the key. Workaround is to call twice with both paths

Comment: @Locka is this supposed to output "null" when the registry value is not found? How can I check if what I want to display is empty or not?

Comment: Lines 32 and 37 can be changed to 4 spaces for parsing. Someone at Microsoft probably preferred 4 space tabbing instead of using the \t character in windows. Since my application is only using the registry for one query this works fine for me. Contact me if you guys need further help

Comment: Not only that (at least on Win 8.1) reg.exe returns spaces instead of tabs, the 0x0D 0x0A at the end should be stripped in order to return the correct value.

Comment: I am getting 'null' as output when I run the aforementioned program.. donno why. Command works fine when I copy paste it in terminal.

Answer (score 86):

[Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) is an excellent project for working with native libraries and has support for the Windows registry in the platform library (platform.jar) through [Advapi32Util](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html) and [Advapi32](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.html).

**Update:** Here's a snippet with some examples of how easy it is to use JNA to work with the Windows registry using JNA 3.4.1,

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg;

public class WindowsRegistrySnippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read a string
        String productName = Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(
            WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductName");
        System.out.printf("Product Name: %s\n", productName);

        // Read an int (& 0xFFFFFFFFL for large unsigned int)
        int timeout = Advapi32Util.registryGetIntValue(
            WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows", "ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout");
        System.out.printf("Shutdown Warning Dialog Timeout: %d (%d as unsigned long)\n", timeout, timeout & 0xFFFFFFFFL);

        // Create a key and write a string
        Advapi32Util.registryCreateKey(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\StackOverflow");
        Advapi32Util.registrySetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\StackOverflow", "url", "http://stackoverflow.com/a/6287763/277307");

        // Delete a key
        Advapi32Util.registryDeleteKey(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\StackOverflow");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is LGPL which might be an issue including it in commercial software.

Comment: @likejiujitsu: The author is willing to sell commercial licenses according to the GitHub page.

Comment: @kevinarpe "Commercial license arrangements are negotiable". Not having a set price is a red flag for me.

Comment: In my experience, LGPL licensed software can be redistributed with commercial software (GPL is much more restrictive).  Of course, you should always consult with your legal department (and probably already have).  It also looks like JNA will be dual licensed to allow redistribution under Apache 2.0 when JNA 4.0 is released (see https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: Can I create multiple subkeys in a single statement by using the method `registryCreateKey(HKEY,keyName)` as `Advapi32Util.registryCreateKey(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\StackOverflow\\MyApp\\Version");`?

Comment: @RomanticElectron Yes, it will create multiple subkeys.  The method is a wrapper around `RegCreateKeyEx`.  The MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx) state, "The RegCreateKeyEx function creates all missing keys in the specified path. An application can take advantage of this behavior to create several keys at once."  A quick test verified this behavior.

Comment: JNA 4.0+ is now Apache 2 licensed ([see here](https://github.com/twall/jna#license)). A big +1 for a non-hacky solution.

Comment: @JohnMcCarthy This code not working Linux(CentOS7) environment. Please give me any other solution.

Comment: @ChetanBhagat I don't understand what you're trying to do. This is about working with the [Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry), which is very specific to the Windows operating system. There's no equivalent to the registry on linux. See [Linux equivalent of Windows Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/295635/linux-equivalent-of-windows-registry/295636)

Comment: LGPL won't cause commercial issue, just GPL does, though.

Answer (score 27):

I've incremented the Pure java code originally posted by David to allow acessing the 32-bits section of the registry from a 64-bit JVM, and vice-versa. I don't think any of the other answers address this.

Here it is:

```
/**
 * Pure Java Windows Registry access.
 * Modified by petrucio@stackoverflow(828681) to add support for
 * reading (and writing but not creating/deleting keys) the 32-bits
 * registry view from a 64-bits JVM (KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
 * and 64-bits view from a 32-bits JVM (KEY_WOW64_64KEY).
 *****************************************************************************/

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {
  public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
  public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
  public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
  public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
  public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

  public static final int KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x0200;
  public static final int KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100;

  private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
  private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
  private static Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
  private static Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
  private static Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
  private static Method regOpenKey = null;
  private static Method regCloseKey = null;
  private static Method regQueryValueEx = null;
  private static Method regEnumValue = null;
  private static Method regQueryInfoKey = null;
  private static Method regEnumKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regCreateKeyEx = null;
  private static Method regSetValueEx = null;
  private static Method regDeleteKey = null;
  private static Method regDeleteValue = null;

  static {
    try {
      regOpenKey     = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey",     new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, int.class });
      regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
      regCloseKey    = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey",    new Class[] { int.class });
      regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryValueEx= userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx",new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
      regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumValue   = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue",   new Class[] { int.class, int.class, int.class });
      regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
      regQueryInfoKey=userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1",new Class[] { int.class });
      regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
      regEnumKeyEx   = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumKeyEx",   new Class[] { int.class, int.class, int.class });  
      regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
      regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });
      regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);  
      regSetValueEx  = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegSetValueEx",  new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class, byte[].class });  
      regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });  
      regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true); 
      regDeleteKey   = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteKey",   new Class[] { int.class, byte[].class });  
      regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private WinRegistry() {  }

  /**
   * Read a value from key and value name
   * @param hkey   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @param wow64  0 for standard registry access (32-bits for 32-bit app, 64-bits for 64-bits app)
   *               or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to force access to 32-bit registry view,
   *               or KEY_WOW64_64KEY to force access to 64-bit registry view
   * @return the value
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName, int wow64) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, wow64);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, wow64);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key 
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param wow64  0 for standard registry access (32-bits for 32-bit app, 64-bits for 64-bits app)
   *               or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to force access to 32-bit registry view,
   *               or KEY_WOW64_64KEY to force access to 64-bit registry view
   * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(int hkey, String key, int wow64) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringValues(systemRoot, hkey, key, wow64);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringValues(userRoot, hkey, key, wow64);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read the value name(s) from a given key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @param wow64  0 for standard registry access (32-bits for 32-bit app, 64-bits for 64-bits app)
   *               or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to force access to 32-bit registry view,
   *               or KEY_WOW64_64KEY to force access to 64-bit registry view
   * @return the value name(s)
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key, int wow64) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key, wow64);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key, wow64);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a key
   * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int [] ret;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
      regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
    if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Write a value in a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param valueName
   * @param value
   * @param wow64  0 for standard registry access (32-bits for 32-bit app, 64-bits for 64-bits app)
   *               or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to force access to 32-bit registry view,
   *               or KEY_WOW64_64KEY to force access to 64-bit registry view
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void writeStringValue
    (int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value, int wow64) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value, wow64);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value, wow64);
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Delete a given key
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
    }
  }

  /**
   * delete a value from a given key/value name
   * @param hkey
   * @param key
   * @param value
   * @param wow64  0 for standard registry access (32-bits for 32-bit app, 64-bits for 64-bits app)
   *               or KEY_WOW64_32KEY to force access to 32-bit registry view,
   *               or KEY_WOW64_64KEY to force access to 64-bit registry view
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value, int wow64) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc = -1;
    if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
      rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value, wow64);
    }
    else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
      rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value, wow64);
    }
    if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
    }
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static int deleteValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value, int wow64)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS | wow64)
    });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return handles[1];  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
    }
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root, new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) 
          })).intValue();
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return rc;
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) 
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int rc =((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)
    })).intValue();
    return rc;  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value, int wow64)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ | wow64)
    });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null; 
    }
    byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value)
    });
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static Map<String,String> readStringValues(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, int wow64)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ | wow64)
    });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0])
    });

    int count  = info[2]; // count  
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer(handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
      });
      String value = readString(hkey, key, new String(name), wow64);
      results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static List<String> readStringSubKeys(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, int wow64)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ | wow64) 
        });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null;
    }
    int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0])
    });

    int count  = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by Petrucio
    int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
    for(int index=0; index<count; index++)  {
      byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
          new Integer(handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)
          });
      results.add(new String(name).trim());
    }
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return results;
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static int [] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    return (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
      new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)
    });
  }

  //========================================================================
  private static void writeStringValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value, int wow64)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS | wow64)
    });
    regSetValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] { 
          new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value) 
          }); 
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
  }

  //========================================================================
  // utility
  private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
    byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
    }
    result[str.length()] = 0;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: good job. This solution helps if you want to access the 32 Bit Registry in a 64Bit JRE and vice versa

Comment: So the readString basically reads the corresponding values once I give in the path? Like when calling this method I should for the hkey insert in where I'm wanting the read to be from right?

Comment: @Petrucio This code not working Linux(CentOS7) environment. Please give me any other solution.

Comment: @ChetanBhagat Sorry mate, I'm not developing Java for a while, much less in Linux. You gotta find yourself your own solution.

Comment: Under Java11 (and perhaps earlier) some of the types have to be changed from `int` to `long` to make this work again.

Answer (score 23):

I've done this before using [jRegistryKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jregistrykey/). It is an LGPL Java/JNI library that can do what you need. Here's an example of how I used it to enabled Registry editing through regedit and also the "Show Folder Options" option for myself in Windows via the registry.

```
import java.io.File;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryKey;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RegistryValue;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.RootKey;
import ca.beq.util.win32.registry.ValueType;


public class FixStuff {

private static final String REGEDIT_KEY = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
private static final String REGEDIT_VALUE = "DisableRegistryTools";
private static final String REGISTRY_LIBRARY_PATH = "\\lib\\jRegistryKey.dll";
private static final String FOLDER_OPTIONS_KEY = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer";
private static final String FOLDER_OPTIONS_VALUE = "NoFolderOptions";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Load JNI library
    RegistryKey.initialize( new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+REGISTRY_LIBRARY_PATH );

    enableRegistryEditing(true);        
    enableShowFolderOptions(true);
}

private static void enableShowFolderOptions(boolean enable) {
    RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,FOLDER_OPTIONS_KEY);
    RegistryKey key2 = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,FOLDER_OPTIONS_KEY);
    RegistryValue value = new RegistryValue();
    value.setName(FOLDER_OPTIONS_VALUE);
    value.setType(ValueType.REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    value.setData(enable?0:1);

    if(key.hasValue(FOLDER_OPTIONS_VALUE)) {
        key.setValue(value);
    }
    if(key2.hasValue(FOLDER_OPTIONS_VALUE)) {
        key2.setValue(value);
    }           
}

private static void enableRegistryEditing(boolean enable) {
    RegistryKey key = new RegistryKey(RootKey.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,REGEDIT_KEY);
    RegistryValue value = new RegistryValue();
    value.setName(REGEDIT_VALUE);
    value.setType(ValueType.REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    value.setData(enable?0:1);

    if(key.hasValue(REGEDIT_VALUE)) {
        key.setValue(value);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This doesn't support 64 bit! The guy that wrote it needs your help to add 64 bit JVM support. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2966672&group_id=104321&atid=641035

Comment: It's also not available on Maven Central.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, using the java.util.Preferences API, since the Windows implementation of it uses the Registry as a backend.

In the end it depends on what you're wanting to do: storing preferences for your app is what the Preferences does just great. If you're wanting to actually change registry keys not having to do with your app, you'll need some JNI app, as described by Mark (shameless steal here):

> From a quick google:
> Check the WinPack for JNIWrapper. It has full Windows Registry access support including Reading and Writing.
>
> The WinPack Demo has Registry Viewer implemented as an example.
>
> Check at http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/#registry_access
>
> And...
>
> There is also try JNIRegistry @ http://www.trustice.com/java/jnireg/
>
> There is also the option of invoking an external app, which is responsible for reading / writing the registry.

Comment: So, how does one edits HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with the Preferences API?

Comment: To do that you'll need a JNI app

Answer (score 11):

From a quick google:

> Check the WinPack for JNIWrapper. It
>   has full Windows Registry access
>   support including Reading and Writing.
>
> The WinPack Demo has Registry Viewer
>   implemented as an example.
>
> Check at
>   http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/#registry_access

And...

> There is also try JNIRegistry @
>   http://www.trustice.com/java/jnireg/

There is also the option of invoking an external app, which is responsible for reading / writing the registry.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to original post. I have reskinned this utility class and come up over the flaws which it had earlier, thought it might help others so posting here. I have also added some extra utility methods. Now it is able to read any file in windows registry(including REG_DWORD, REG_BINARY, REG_EXPAND_SZ etc.). All the methods work like a charm. Just copy and paste it and it should work. Here is the reskinned and modified class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {

    private static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;
    private static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;
    private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;
    private static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;
    private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;
    public static final int HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000;
    public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001;
    public static final int HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
    private static final String CLASSES_ROOT = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT";
    private static final String CURRENT_USER = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
    private static final String LOCAL_MACHINE = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE";
    private static Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
    private static Preferences systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    private static Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
    private static Method regOpenKey = null;
    private static Method regCloseKey = null;
    private static Method regQueryValueEx = null;
    private static Method regEnumValue = null;
    private static Method regQueryInfoKey = null;
    private static Method regEnumKeyEx = null;
    private static Method regCreateKeyEx = null;
    private static Method regSetValueEx = null;
    private static Method regDeleteKey = null;
    private static Method regDeleteValue = null;

    static {
        try {
            regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class, int.class});
            regOpenKey.setAccessible(true);
            regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey", new Class[] {int.class});
            regCloseKey.setAccessible(true);
            regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class});
            regQueryValueEx.setAccessible(true);
            regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue", new Class[] {int.class, int.class, int.class});
            regEnumValue.setAccessible(true);
            regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1", new Class[] {int.class});
            regQueryInfoKey.setAccessible(true);
            regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[] {int.class, int.class, int.class});  
            regEnumKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
            regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class});  
            regCreateKeyEx.setAccessible(true);
            regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class, byte[].class});  
            regSetValueEx.setAccessible(true);
            regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class});  
            regDeleteValue.setAccessible(true);
            regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[] {int.class, byte[].class});  
            regDeleteKey.setAccessible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads value for the key from given path
     * @param hkey   HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param path
     * @param key
     * @return the value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static String valueForKey(int hkey, String path, String key) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            return valueForKey(systemRoot, hkey, path, key);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            return valueForKey(userRoot, hkey, path, key);
        else
            return valueForKey(null, hkey, path, key);
    }

    /**
     * Reads all key(s) and value(s) from given path
     * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param path
     * @return the map of key(s) and corresponding value(s)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static Map<String, String> valuesForPath(int hkey, String path) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            return valuesForPath(systemRoot, hkey, path);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            return valuesForPath(userRoot, hkey, path);
        else
            return valuesForPath(null, hkey, path);
    }

    /**
     * Read all the subkey(s) from a given path
     * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param path
     * @return the subkey(s) list
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static List<String> subKeysForPath(int hkey, String path)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            return subKeysForPath(systemRoot, hkey, path);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            return subKeysForPath(userRoot, hkey, path);
        else
            return subKeysForPath(null, hkey, path);
    }

    /**
     * Create a key
     * @param hkey  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int [] ret;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) {
            ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
            regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
        } else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER) {
            ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
            regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[] { new Integer(ret[0]) });
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + "  key=" + key);
    }

    /**
     * Write a value in a given key/value name
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param valueName
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void writeStringValue(int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
    }

    /**
     * Delete a given key
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int rc = -1;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key);
    }

    /**
     * delete a value from a given key/value name
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int rc = -1;
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + "  key=" + key + "  value=" + value);
    }

    // =====================

    private static int deleteValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
            return handles[1];                                  // can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
        int rc =((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value)})).intValue();
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0])});
        return rc;
    }

    private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int rc =((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)})).intValue();
        return rc;                                                  // can REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
    }

    private static String valueForKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String path, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(path), new Integer(KEY_READ)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The system can not find the specified path: '"+getParentKey(hkey)+"\\"+path+"'");
        byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(key)});
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
        return (valb != null ? parseValue(valb) : queryValueForKey(hkey, path, key));
    }

    private static String queryValueForKey(int hkey, String path, String key) throws IOException {
        return queryValuesForPath(hkey, path).get(key);
    }

    private static Map<String,String> valuesForPath(Preferences root, int hkey, String path)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String,String>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(path), new Integer(KEY_READ)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The system can not find the specified path: '"+getParentKey(hkey)+"\\"+path+"'");
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
        int count = info[2];                            // Fixed: info[0] was being used here
        int maxlen = info[4];                           // while info[3] was being used here, causing wrong results
        for(int index=0; index<count; index++) {
            byte[] valb = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
            String vald = parseValue(valb);
            if(valb == null || vald.isEmpty())
                return queryValuesForPath(hkey, path);
            results.put(vald, valueForKey(root, hkey, path, vald));
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Searches recursively into the path to find the value for key. This method gives 
     * only first occurrence value of the key. If required to get all values in the path 
     * recursively for this key, then {@link #valuesForKeyPath(int hkey, String path, String key)} 
     * should be used.
     * @param hkey
     * @param path
     * @param key
     * @param list
     * @return the value of given key obtained recursively
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static String valueForKeyPath(int hkey, String path, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        String val;
        try {
            val = valuesForKeyPath(hkey, path, key).get(0);
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The system can not find the key: '"+key+"' after "
                    + "searching the specified path: '"+getParentKey(hkey)+"\\"+path+"'");
        }
        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Searches recursively into given path for particular key and stores obtained value in list
     * @param hkey
     * @param path
     * @param key
     * @param list
     * @return list containing values for given key obtained recursively
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<String> valuesForKeyPath(int hkey, String path, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            return valuesForKeyPath(systemRoot, hkey, path, key, list);
        else if (hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            return valuesForKeyPath(userRoot, hkey, path, key, list);
        else
            return valuesForKeyPath(null, hkey, path, key, list);
    }

    private static List<String> valuesForKeyPath(Preferences root, int hkey, String path, String key, List<String> list)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        if(!isDirectory(root, hkey, path)) {
            takeValueInListForKey(hkey, path, key, list);
        } else {
            List<String> subKeys = subKeysForPath(root, hkey, path);
            for(String subkey: subKeys) {
                String newPath = path+"\\"+subkey;
                if(isDirectory(root, hkey, newPath))
                    valuesForKeyPath(root, hkey, newPath, key, list);
                takeValueInListForKey(hkey, newPath, key, list);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Takes value for key in list
     * @param hkey
     * @param path
     * @param key
     * @param list
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void takeValueInListForKey(int hkey, String path, String key, List<String> list)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        String value = valueForKey(hkey, path, key);
        if(value != null)
            list.add(value);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the path has more subkeys or not
     * @param root
     * @param hkey
     * @param path
     * @return true if path has subkeys otherwise false
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    private static boolean isDirectory(Preferences root, int hkey, String path)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return !subKeysForPath(root, hkey, path).isEmpty();
    }

    private static List<String> subKeysForPath(Preferences root, int hkey, String path)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(path), new Integer(KEY_READ)});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The system can not find the specified path: '"+getParentKey(hkey)+"\\"+path+"'");
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
        int count  = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by Petrucio
        int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
        for(int index=0; index<count; index++) {
            byte[] valb = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0]), new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1)});
            results.add(parseValue(valb));
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
        return results;
    }

    private static int [] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key)});
    }

    private static void writeStringValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)});
        regSetValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value)}); 
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {new Integer(handles[0])});
    }

    /**
     * Makes cmd query for the given hkey and path then executes the query
     * @param hkey
     * @param path
     * @return the map containing all results in form of key(s) and value(s) obtained by executing query
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static Map<String, String> queryValuesForPath(int hkey, String path) throws IOException {
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query \""+getParentKey(hkey)+"\\" + path + "\"");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!line.contains("REG_"))
                continue;
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " \t");
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if(token.startsWith("REG_"))
                    builder.append("\t ");
                else
                    builder.append(token).append(" ");
            }
            String[] arr = builder.toString().split("\t");
            map.put(arr[0].trim(), arr[1].trim());
            builder.setLength(0);
        }
        return map;
    }

    /**
     * Determines the string equivalent of hkey
     * @param hkey
     * @return string equivalent of hkey
     */
    private static String getParentKey(int hkey) {
        if(hkey == HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
            return CLASSES_ROOT;
        else if(hkey == HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
            return CURRENT_USER;
        else if(hkey == HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
            return LOCAL_MACHINE;
        return null;
    }

    /**
     *Intern method which adds the trailing \0 for the handle with java.dll
     * @param str String
     * @return byte[] 
     */
    private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
        if(str == null)
            str = "";
        return (str += "\0").getBytes();
    }

    /**
     * Method removes the trailing \0 which is returned from the java.dll (just if the last sign is a \0)
     * @param buf the byte[] buffer which every read method returns
     * @return String a parsed string without the trailing \0
     */
    private static String parseValue(byte buf[]) {
        if(buf == null)
            return null;
        String ret = new String(buf);
        if(ret.charAt(ret.length()-1) == '\0')
            return ret.substring(0, ret.length()-1);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Sample of using the methods is as follows:**

Below method retrieves the value of the key from the given path:

```
String hex = WinRegistry.valueForKey(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update", "AUOptions");
```

This method retrieves all data for the specified path(in form of keys and values) :

```
Map<String, String> map = WinRegistry.valuesForPath(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WSMAN");
```

This method retrieves value recursively for the key from the given path:

```
String val = WinRegistry.valueForKeyPath(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "System", "TypeID");
```

and this one retrieves all values recursively for a key from the given path:

```
List<String> list = WinRegistry.valuesForKeyPath(
                   WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                  //HKEY                               "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall",   //path                 "DisplayName"         //Key
            );
```

Here in above code I retrieved all installed software names in windows system.
**Note: See the documentation of these methods**

And this one retrieves all subkeys of the given path:

```
List<String> list3 = WinRegistry.subKeysForPath(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software");
```

**Important Note: I have modified only reading purpose methods in this process, not the writing purpose methods like createKey, deleteKey etc. They still are same as I recieved them.**

Comment: when i write registry to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, error shown as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rc=5   key=SOFTWARE\rgagnon.com\aa. WinRegistry.createKey(WinRegistry.java:157). how to solve it.

Comment: please read important note in the last, i have not modified writing registry purpose methods, they are same as recieved.

Comment: Be very careful wit this solution, it is NOT the same as the accepted answer.  At the very bottom level it replaces the call to the Preference class with shelling out to the "reg query" command, but it looks enough like the accepted answer that you might not realize this right away.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a modified version of Oleg's solution.  I noticed that on my system (Windows server 2003), the output of "reg query" is not separated by tabs ('\t'), but by 4 spaces.

I also simplified the solution, as a thread is not required.

```
public static final String readRegistry(String location, String key)
{
  try
  {
      // Run reg query, then read output with StreamReader (internal class)
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + 
              '"'+ location + "\" /v " + key);

      InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
      StringBuilder sw = new StringBuilder();

      try
      {
         int c;
         while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
             sw.append((char)c);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      { 
      }

      String output = sw.toString();

      // Output has the following format:
      // \n<Version information>\n\n<key>    <registry type>    <value>\r\n\r\n
      int i = output.indexOf("REG_SZ");
      if (i == -1)
      {
          return null;
      }

      sw = new StringBuilder();
      i += 6; // skip REG_SZ

      // skip spaces or tabs
      for (;;)
      {
         if (i > output.length())
             break;
         char c = output.charAt(i);
         if (c != ' ' && c != '\t')
             break;
         ++i;
      }

      // take everything until end of line
      for (;;)
      {
         if (i > output.length())
             break;
         char c = output.charAt(i);
         if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
             break;
         sw.append(c);
         ++i;
      }

      return sw.toString();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      return null;
  }
```

}

Comment: Even tho this is nearly 10 years old, it's still one of the top google result, so an advice to future users: make two reg-queries, one with "/reg:32" and one with "/reg:64" to ensure it works correctly. For example, Steam for me is 64 bit. querying HKLM\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam\InstallPath fails unless I add a /reg:32, because the "real" key is HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve..

Comment: Correction: steam is 32 bit, my os is 64 bit. Sorry, too late to edit

Answer (score 7):

The best way to write to the register probably is using the `reg import` native Windows command and giving it the file path to the `.reg` file which has been generated by exporting something from the registry.

Reading is done with the `reg query` command. Also see the documentation:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx

Therefore the following code should be self-explanatory:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class WindowsRegistry
{
    public static void importSilently(String regFilePath) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException
    {
        if (!new File(regFilePath).exists())
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        Process importer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg import " + regFilePath);

        importer.waitFor();
    }

    public static void overwriteValue(String keyPath, String keyName,
            String keyValue) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Process overwriter = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "reg add " + keyPath + " /t REG_SZ /v \"" + keyName + "\" /d "
                        + keyValue + " /f");

        overwriter.waitFor();
    }

    public static String getValue(String keyPath, String keyName)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        Process keyReader = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "reg query \"" + keyPath + "\" /v \"" + keyName + "\"");

        BufferedReader outputReader;
        String readLine;
        StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        outputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                keyReader.getInputStream()));

        while ((readLine = outputReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            outputBuffer.append(readLine);
        }

        String[] outputComponents = outputBuffer.toString().split("    ");

        keyReader.waitFor();

        return outputComponents[outputComponents.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As has been noted, the Preferences API uses the registry to store preferences, but cannot be used to access the whole registry.

However, a pirate called David Croft has worked out that it's possible to use methods in Sun's implementation of the Preferences API for [reading the Windows registry from Java without JNI](http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/reading-windows-registry-java-without-jni). There are some dangers to that, but it is worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

The Preferences API approach does not give you access to all the branches of the registry. In fact, it only gives you access to where the Preferences API stores its, well, preferences. It's not a generic registry handling API, like .NET's

To read/write every key I guess JNI or an external tool would be the approach to take, as Mark shows.

Comment: I hate how the Preferences API is actually preferences for Java itself. I wish it'd be more generic like you said.

Answer (score 4):

There are few JNDI service providers to work with windows registry.

One could observe [http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/serviceproviders.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120801053337/http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/serviceproviders.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could try [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/). This is a windows java launcher and service host but it also provides a library for accessing the registry.

(btw I work on this project so let me know if you have any questions)

Answer (score 3):

My previous edit to @David's answer was rejected.  Here is some useful information about it.

This "magic" works because Sun implements the `Preferences` class for Windows as part of JDK, but it is [package private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).  Parts of the implementation use JNI.

- Package private class from JDK `java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/prefs/WindowsPreferences.java
- JNI: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/native/java/util/WindowsPreferences.c

The implementation is selected at runtime using a factory method here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/prefs/Preferences.java#Preferences.0factory

The real question: Why doesn't OpenJDK expose this API to public?

Comment: All JDK functions are supposed to work on any operating system, so they don't make WindowsPreferences public but just Preferences, which contains functions that should work everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `java.util.prefs` package provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system preferences and data configuration. These preference data will be stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing stored. For example in Windows operating system in will stored in Windows registry.

To write and read these data we use the `java.util.prefs.Preferences` class. Below code shows how to read and write to the `HKCU` and `HKLM` in the registry.

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class RegistryDemo {
    public static final String PREF_KEY = "org.username";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        // Write Preferences information to HKCU (HKEY_CURRENT_USER),
        // HKCU\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\org.username
        //
        Preferences userPref = Preferences.userRoot();
        userPref.put(PREF_KEY, "xyz");

        //
        // Below we read back the value we've written in the code above.
        //
        System.out.println("Preferences = "
                + userPref.get(PREF_KEY, PREF_KEY + " was not found."));

        //
        // Write Preferences information to HKLM (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE),
        // HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\org.username
        //
        Preferences systemPref = Preferences.systemRoot();
        systemPref.put(PREF_KEY, "xyz");

        //
        // Read back the value we've written in the code above.
        //
        System.out.println("Preferences = "
                + systemPref.get(PREF_KEY, PREF_KEY + " was not found."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another library...

https://code.google.com/p/java-registry/

This one launches reg.exe under the covers, reading/writing to temporary files. I didn't end up using it, but it looks like a pretty comprehensive implementation. If I did use it, I might dive in and add some better management of the child processes.

Comment: Does not provide a native implementation but just calls regedit.exe a lot.

Comment: Works just fine.

Comment: @AlexByrth may work fine for you, but (1) does not work for software that cannot write files locally, which does indeed happen, (2) will fail as soon as reg.exe changes the input or output format, (3) will fail when you code for corporate customers that, for some security reason, disable calling reg.exe, or calling any programs at all (yes, these do exist). Also, calling out to an external program is slow on Windows.

Comment: @toolforger, good points, but the proposed solution solved my issues. The situations you described are dead ends for several other options out there too. There is no easy general fix for this, except perhaps a full-featured installer package running as administrator. A bazooka to kill an ant.

Comment: @AlexByrth "works for me" is good for "needs to work for nobody except me" situations. Most code must work for others, and then solutions like those based on external programs that use an undocumented output format that may change with every Windows version simply don't fly. The JNA-based solutions work against a documented MS API - this doesn't mean it will never change, but at least you'll get a warning, and probably the JNA library will be updated in time so you won't even notice something changed.

Comment: @toolforger, Thanks for your points. But "general and stable solution" in MS Windows is something not easily achievable. If you ever used an API from MS, you know it is deprecated and broke in a couple of years. Nevertheless, RegEdit is one of the most stable things in MS-Windows. Unless WIndows stop using registry, one day. But this is another story...

Comment: @toolforger By the way, I've tried JNA. I fount it a bit fine-grained and don't have enough man-hours to master it. Maybe on next Windows show stopper issue.

Comment: @AlexByrth I doubt that the registry API has changed much. And yes I have been there, done that - collaborated on an OO wrapper around Windows GDI :-) (there *are* instabilities and unexpected changes, but they rarely affect the basic API, more the semantics behind it).

Answer (score 1):

I make my own code using enum.

```
    public class Registry {

    public static enum key {
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG;
    };

    public static enum dataType {
        REG_BINARY, REG_DWORD, REG_EXPAND_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ, REG_SZ, REG_RESOURCE_LIST, REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST, REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR, REG_NONE, REG_LINK, REG_QWORD;
    }

    public static enum userKey {
        AppEvents, Console, Control_Panel, Enviroment, EUDC, Keyboard_Layout, Microsoft, Network, Printers, Software, System, Uninstall, Volatile_Enviroment;
    }

    public static void overWriteSoftwareInt(String key, String userKey, String path, String valueKey, String datatype, int value) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg add " + key + "\\" + userKey + "\\" + path + " /t " + datatype + " /v \"" + valueKey + "\" /d " + value);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //  Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static void overWriteSoftwareString(String key, String userKey, String path, String valueKey, String datatype, int value) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg add " + key + "\\" + userKey + "\\" + path + " /t " + datatype + " /v \"" + valueKey + "\" /d \"" + value+"\"");
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //  Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteValue(String key, String userKey, String path, String valueKey) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg delete " + key + "\\" + userKey + "\\" + path + " /v \"" + valueKey + "\" /f");
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //  Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this class following this example.

```
   Registry.deleteValue(Registry.key.HKEY_CURRENT_USER.name(), Registry.userKey.Software.name(), "path", "valueName");
   Registry.overWriteSoftwareInt(Registry.key.HKEY_CURRENT_USER.name(), Registry.userKey.Software.name(), "path", "valueName", Registry.dataType.REG_DWORD.name(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The WinPack Demo has Registry Viewer
>   implemented as an example.
>
> Check at
>   http://www.jniwrapper.com/winpack_features.jsp#registry

BTW, WinPack has been moved to the following address:

http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is pretty old, but i guess the better utility to use on windows platform would be `regini` :

A single call to process:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("regini <your script file abs path here>");
```

will do all the magic. I have tried it, while making jar as windows service using servany.exe which requires changes to made in registry for adding javaw.exe arguments and it works perfectly. You might want to read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264584

Answer (score 0):

This was crazy... I took the code from one of the posts here, failed to see there were 18 more comments in which one stated that it does not read a dword value...

In any case, I've refactored the hell of that code into something with less ifs and methods...

The Enum could be refined a bit, but as soon as I've fought my way to read a numeric value or byte array and failed, I've given up...

So here it is:

```
package com.nu.art.software.utils;


import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

/**
 *
 * @author TacB0sS
 */
public class WinRegistry_TacB0sS {

    public static final class RegistryException
            extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8799947496460994651L;

        public RegistryException(String message, Throwable e) {
            super(message, e);
        }

        public RegistryException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }


    }

    public static final int KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x0200;

    public static final int KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100;

    public static final int REG_SUCCESS = 0;

    public static final int REG_NOTFOUND = 2;

    public static final int REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5;

    private static final int KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f;

    private static final int KEY_READ = 0x20019;

    public enum WinRegistryKey {
        User(Preferences.userRoot(), 0x80000001), ;

        // System(Preferences.systemRoot(), 0x80000002);

        private final Preferences preferencesRoot;

        private final Integer key;

        private WinRegistryKey(Preferences preferencesRoot, int key) {
            this.preferencesRoot = preferencesRoot;
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    private enum WinRegistryMethod {
        OpenKey("WindowsRegOpenKey", int.class, byte[].class, int.class) {

            @Override
            protected void verifyReturnValue(Object retValue)
                    throws RegistryException {
                int[] retVal = (int[]) retValue;
                if (retVal[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
                    throw new RegistryException("Action Failed, Return Code: " + retVal[1]);
            }
        },
        CreateKeyEx("WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", int.class, byte[].class) {

            @Override
            protected void verifyReturnValue(Object retValue)
                    throws RegistryException {
                int[] retVal = (int[]) retValue;
                if (retVal[1] != REG_SUCCESS)
                    throw new RegistryException("Action Failed, Return Code: " + retVal[1]);
            }
        },
        DeleteKey("WindowsRegDeleteKey", int.class, byte[].class) {

            @Override
            protected void verifyReturnValue(Object retValue)
                    throws RegistryException {
                int retVal = ((Integer) retValue).intValue();
                if (retVal != REG_SUCCESS)
                    throw new RegistryException("Action Failed, Return Code: " + retVal);
            }
        },
        DeleteValue("WindowsRegDeleteValue", int.class, byte[].class) {

            @Override
            protected void verifyReturnValue(Object retValue)
                    throws RegistryException {
                int retVal = ((Integer) retValue).intValue();
                if (retVal != REG_SUCCESS)
                    throw new RegistryException("Action Failed, Return Code: " + retVal);
            }
        },
        CloseKey("WindowsRegCloseKey", int.class),
        QueryValueEx("WindowsRegQueryValueEx", int.class, byte[].class),
        EnumKeyEx("WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", int.class, int.class, int.class),
        EnumValue("WindowsRegEnumValue", int.class, int.class, int.class),
        QueryInfoKey("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey", int.class),
        SetValueEx("WindowsRegSetValueEx", int.class, byte[].class, byte[].class);

        private Method method;

        private WinRegistryMethod(String methodName, Class<?>... classes) {
            // WinRegistryKey.User.preferencesRoot.getClass().getMDeclaredMethods()
            try {
                method = WinRegistryKey.User.preferencesRoot.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, classes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error");
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            method.setAccessible(true);
        }

        public Object invoke(Preferences root, Object... objects)
                throws RegistryException {
            Object retValue;
            try {
                retValue = method.invoke(root, objects);
                verifyReturnValue(retValue);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                String params = "";
                if (objects.length > 0) {
                    params = objects[0].toString();
                    for (int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++) {
                        params += ", " + objects[i];
                    }
                }
                throw new RegistryException("Error invoking method: " + method + ", with params: (" + params + ")", e);
            }
            return retValue;
        }

        protected void verifyReturnValue(Object retValue)
                throws RegistryException {}
    }

    private WinRegistry_TacB0sS() {}

    public static String readString(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key, String valueName)
            throws RegistryException {
        int retVal = ((int[]) WinRegistryMethod.OpenKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key),
                new Integer(KEY_READ)))[0];

        byte[] retValue = (byte[]) WinRegistryMethod.QueryValueEx.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal,
                toCstr(valueName));
        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);

        /*
         * Should this return an Empty String.
         */
        return (retValue != null ? new String(retValue).trim() : null);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key)
            throws RegistryException {
        HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
        int retVal = ((int[]) WinRegistryMethod.OpenKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key),
                new Integer(KEY_READ)))[0];

        int[] info = (int[]) WinRegistryMethod.QueryInfoKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);

        int count = info[2]; // count
        int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) WinRegistryMethod.EnumValue.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal,
                    new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1));
            String value = readString(regKey, key, new String(name));
            results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
        }

        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);
        return results;
    }

    public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key)
            throws RegistryException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        int retVal = ((int[]) WinRegistryMethod.OpenKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key),
                new Integer(KEY_READ)))[0];

        int[] info = (int[]) WinRegistryMethod.QueryInfoKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);

        int count = info[0]; // Fix: info[2] was being used here with wrong results. Suggested by davenpcj, confirmed by
                                // Petrucio
        int maxlen = info[3]; // value length max
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) WinRegistryMethod.EnumValue.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal,
                    new Integer(index), new Integer(maxlen + 1));
            results.add(new String(name).trim());
        }

        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);
        return results;
    }

    public static void createKey(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key)
            throws RegistryException {
        int[] retVal = (int[]) WinRegistryMethod.CreateKeyEx.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key));
        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal[0]);
    }

    public static void writeStringValue(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key, String valueName, String value)
            throws RegistryException {
        int retVal = ((int[]) WinRegistryMethod.OpenKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key),
                new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)))[0];

        WinRegistryMethod.SetValueEx.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal, toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value));
        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);
    }

    public static void deleteKey(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key)
            throws RegistryException {
        WinRegistryMethod.DeleteKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key));
    }

    public static void deleteValue(WinRegistryKey regKey, String key, String value)
            throws RegistryException {
        int retVal = ((int[]) WinRegistryMethod.OpenKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, regKey.key, toCstr(key),
                new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS)))[0];
        WinRegistryMethod.DeleteValue.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal, toCstr(value));
        WinRegistryMethod.CloseKey.invoke(regKey.preferencesRoot, retVal);
    }

    // utility
    private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {
        byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
        }
        result[str.length()] = '\0';
        return result;
    }
}
```

**NOTE: THIS DOES NOT READ ANYTHING ELSE BUT STRINGS!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

This uses the same Java internal APIs as in [in David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701), but I've rewritten it completely. It's shorter now and nicer to use. I also added support for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and other hives. It still has some of the other limitations though (such as no DWORD support and no Unicode support) which are due to the underlying API and are sadly unavoidable with this approach. Still, if you only need basic string reading/writing and don't want to load a native DLL, it's handy.

I'm sure you can figure out how to use it.

Public domain. Have fun.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Simple registry access class implemented using some private APIs
 * in java.util.prefs. It has no other prerequisites.
 */
public final class WindowsRegistry {
    /**
     * Tells if the Windows registry functions are available.
     * (They will not be available when not running on Windows, for example.)
     */
    public static boolean isAvailable() {
        return initError == null;
    }



    /** Reads a string value from the given key and value name. */
    public static String readValue(String keyName, String valueName) {
        try (Key key = Key.open(keyName, KEY_READ)) {
            return fromByteArray(invoke(regQueryValueEx, key.handle, toByteArray(valueName)));
        }
    }



    /** Returns a map of all the name-value pairs in the given key. */
    public static Map<String,String> readValues(String keyName) {
        try (Key key = Key.open(keyName, KEY_READ)) {
            int[] info = invoke(regQueryInfoKey, key.handle);
            checkError(info[INFO_ERROR_CODE]);
            int count = info[INFO_COUNT_VALUES];
            int maxlen = info[INFO_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH] + 1;
            Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String valueName = fromByteArray(invoke(regEnumValue, key.handle, i, maxlen));
                values.put(valueName, readValue(keyName, valueName));
            }
            return values;
        }
    }



    /** Returns a list of the names of all the subkeys of a key. */
    public static List<String> readSubkeys(String keyName) {
        try (Key key = Key.open(keyName, KEY_READ)) {
            int[] info = invoke(regQueryInfoKey, key.handle);
            checkError(info[INFO_ERROR_CODE]);
            int count = info[INFO_COUNT_KEYS];
            int maxlen = info[INFO_MAX_KEY_LENGTH] + 1;
            List<String> subkeys = new ArrayList<>(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                subkeys.add(fromByteArray(invoke(regEnumKeyEx, key.handle, i, maxlen)));
            }
            return subkeys;
        }
    }



    /** Writes a string value with a given key and value name. */
    public static void writeValue(String keyName, String valueName, String value) {
        try (Key key = Key.open(keyName, KEY_WRITE)) {
            checkError(invoke(regSetValueEx, key.handle, toByteArray(valueName), toByteArray(value)));
        }
    }



    /** Deletes a value within a key. */
    public static void deleteValue(String keyName, String valueName) {
        try (Key key = Key.open(keyName, KEY_WRITE)) {
            checkError(invoke(regDeleteValue, key.handle, toByteArray(valueName)));
        }
    }



    /**
     * Deletes a key and all values within it. If the key has subkeys, an
     * "Access denied" error will be thrown. Subkeys must be deleted separately.
     */
    public static void deleteKey(String keyName) {
        checkError(invoke(regDeleteKey, keyParts(keyName)));
    }



    /**
     * Creates a key. Parent keys in the path will also be created if necessary.
     * This method returns without error if the key already exists.
     */
    public static void createKey(String keyName) {
        int[] info = invoke(regCreateKeyEx, keyParts(keyName));
        checkError(info[INFO_ERROR_CODE]);
        invoke(regCloseKey, info[INFO_HANDLE]);
    }



    /**
     * The exception type that will be thrown if a registry operation fails.
     */
    public static class RegError extends RuntimeException {
        public RegError(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }
    }





    // *************
    // PRIVATE STUFF
    // *************

    private WindowsRegistry() {}


    // Map of registry hive names to constants from winreg.h
    private static final Map<String,Integer> hives = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        hives.put("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT",   0x80000000); hives.put("HKCR", 0x80000000);
        hives.put("HKEY_CURRENT_USER",   0x80000001); hives.put("HKCU", 0x80000001);
        hives.put("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",  0x80000002); hives.put("HKLM", 0x80000002);
        hives.put("HKEY_USERS",          0x80000003); hives.put("HKU",  0x80000003);
        hives.put("HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG", 0x80000005); hives.put("HKCC", 0x80000005);
    }


    // Splits a path such as HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft into a pair of
    // values used by the underlying API: An integer hive constant and a byte array
    // of the key path within that hive.
    private static Object[] keyParts(String fullKeyName) {
        int x = fullKeyName.indexOf('\\');
        String hiveName = x >= 0 ? fullKeyName.substring(0, x)  : fullKeyName;
        String keyName  = x >= 0 ? fullKeyName.substring(x + 1) : "";
        Integer hkey = hives.get(hiveName);
        if (hkey == null) throw new RegError("Unknown registry hive: " + hiveName, null);
        return new Object[] { hkey, toByteArray(keyName) };
    }


    // Type encapsulating a native handle to a registry key
    private static class Key implements AutoCloseable {
        final int handle;

        private Key(int handle) {
            this.handle = handle;
        }

        static Key open(String keyName, int accessMode) {
            Object[] keyParts = keyParts(keyName);
            int[] ret = invoke(regOpenKey, keyParts[0], keyParts[1], accessMode);
            checkError(ret[INFO_ERROR_CODE]);
            return new Key(ret[INFO_HANDLE]);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            invoke(regCloseKey, handle);
        }
    }


    // Array index constants for results of regOpenKey, regCreateKeyEx, and regQueryInfoKey
    private static final int
        INFO_HANDLE = 0,
        INFO_COUNT_KEYS = 0,
        INFO_ERROR_CODE = 1,
        INFO_COUNT_VALUES = 2,
        INFO_MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 3,
        INFO_MAX_VALUE_LENGTH = 4;


    // Registry access mode constants from winnt.h
    private static final int
        KEY_READ = 0x20019,
        KEY_WRITE = 0x20006;


    // Error constants from winerror.h
    private static final int
        ERROR_SUCCESS = 0,
        ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2,
        ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;

    private static void checkError(int e) {
        if (e == ERROR_SUCCESS) return;
        throw new RegError(
            e == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ? "Key not found" :
            e == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED ? "Access denied" :
            ("Error number " + e), null);
    }


    // Registry access methods in java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences
    private static final Method
        regOpenKey = getMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey", int.class, byte[].class, int.class),
        regCloseKey = getMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey", int.class),
        regQueryValueEx = getMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx", int.class, byte[].class),
        regQueryInfoKey = getMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey", int.class),
        regEnumValue = getMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue", int.class, int.class, int.class),
        regEnumKeyEx = getMethod("WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", int.class, int.class, int.class),
        regSetValueEx = getMethod("WindowsRegSetValueEx", int.class, byte[].class, byte[].class),
        regDeleteValue = getMethod("WindowsRegDeleteValue", int.class, byte[].class),
        regDeleteKey = getMethod("WindowsRegDeleteKey", int.class, byte[].class),
        regCreateKeyEx = getMethod("WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", int.class, byte[].class);

    private static Throwable initError;

    private static Method getMethod(String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
        try {
            Method m = java.util.prefs.Preferences.systemRoot().getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            return m;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            initError = t;
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T invoke(Method method, Object... args) {
        if (initError != null)
            throw new RegError("Registry methods are not available", initError);
        try {
            return (T)method.invoke(null, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RegError(null, e);
        }
    }


    // Conversion of strings to/from null-terminated byte arrays.
    // There is no support for Unicode; sorry, this is a limitation
    // of the underlying methods that Java makes available.
    private static byte[] toByteArray(String str) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            bytes[i] = (byte)str.charAt(i);
        return bytes;
    }

    private static String fromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) return null;
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            chars[i] = (char)((int)bytes[i] & 0xFF);
        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

One day, Java will have a built-in [foreign function interface](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/191) for easy access to native APIs, and this sort of hack will be unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

In response to David [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701/2111085) - I would do some enhancements:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class WinRegistry {

    public static final int HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001,
            HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002,
            REG_SUCCESS = 0,
            REG_NOTFOUND = 2,
            REG_ACCESSDENIED = 5,
            KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003f,
            KEY_READ = 0x20019;
    private static final Preferences userRoot = Preferences.userRoot(),
            systemRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
    private static final Class<? extends Preferences> userClass = userRoot.getClass();
    private static Method regOpenKey,
            regCloseKey,
            regQueryValueEx,
            regEnumValue,
            regQueryInfoKey,
            regEnumKeyEx,
            regCreateKeyEx,
            regSetValueEx,
            regDeleteKey,
            regDeleteValue;

    static {
        try {
            (regOpenKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegOpenKey", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class, int.class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regCloseKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCloseKey", new Class[]{int.class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regQueryValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryValueEx", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regEnumValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumValue", new Class[]{int.class, int.class, int.class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regQueryInfoKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegQueryInfoKey1", new Class[]{int.class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regEnumKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegEnumKeyEx", new Class[]{int.class, int.class, int.class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regCreateKeyEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegCreateKeyEx", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regSetValueEx = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegSetValueEx", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class, byte[].class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regDeleteValue = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteValue", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class})).setAccessible(true);
            (regDeleteKey = userClass.getDeclaredMethod("WindowsRegDeleteKey", new Class[]{int.class, byte[].class})).setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WinRegistry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a value from key and value name
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @param valueName
     * @return the value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                return readString(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                return readString(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read value(s) and value name(s) form given key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @return the value name(s) plus the value(s)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static Map<String, String> readStringValues(int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                return readStringValues(systemRoot, hkey, key);
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                return readStringValues(userRoot, hkey, key);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the value name(s) from a given key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @return the value name(s)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static List<String> readStringSubKeys(int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                return readStringSubKeys(systemRoot, hkey, key);
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                return readStringSubKeys(userRoot, hkey, key);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a key
     *
     * @param hkey HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void createKey(int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int[] ret;
        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                ret = createKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
                regCloseKey.invoke(systemRoot, new Object[]{ret[0]});
                break;
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                ret = createKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
                regCloseKey.invoke(userRoot, new Object[]{ret[0]});
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }

        if (ret[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + ret[1] + " key=" + key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write a value in a given key/value name
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param valueName
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void writeStringValue(int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                writeStringValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
                break;
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                writeStringValue(userRoot, hkey, key, valueName, value);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hkey=" + hkey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete a given key
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteKey(int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int rc = -1;
        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                rc = deleteKey(systemRoot, hkey, key);
                break;
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                rc = deleteKey(userRoot, hkey, key);
        }

        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + " key=" + key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * delete a value from a given key/value name
     *
     * @param hkey
     * @param key
     * @param value
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public static void deleteValue(int hkey, String key, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int rc = -1;
        switch (hkey) {
            case HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
                rc = deleteValue(systemRoot, hkey, key, value);
                break;
            case HKEY_CURRENT_USER:
                rc = deleteValue(userRoot, hkey, key, value);
        }

        if (rc != REG_SUCCESS) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rc=" + rc + " key=" + key + " value=" + value);
        }
    }

    private static int deleteValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key), KEY_ALL_ACCESS});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return handles[1];//Can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED
        }
        int rc = ((Integer) regDeleteValue.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0], toCstr(value)}));
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});
        return rc;
    }

    private static int deleteKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int rc = ((Integer) regDeleteKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key)}));
        return rc;  //Can be REG_NOTFOUND, REG_ACCESSDENIED, REG_SUCCESS
    }

    private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key), KEY_READ});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0], toCstr(value)});
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});
        return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> readStringValues(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key), KEY_READ});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});

        int count = info[0]; //Count  
        int maxlen = info[3]; //Max value length
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumValue.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0], index, maxlen + 1});
            String value = readString(hkey, key, new String(name));
            results.put(new String(name).trim(), value);
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});
        return results;
    }

    private static List<String> readStringSubKeys(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key), KEY_READ});
        if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
            return null;
        }
        int[] info = (int[]) regQueryInfoKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});

        int count = info[0];//Count
        int maxlen = info[3]; //Max value length
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            byte[] name = (byte[]) regEnumKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0], index, maxlen + 1});
            results.add(new String(name).trim());
        }
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});
        return results;
    }

    private static int[] createKey(Preferences root, int hkey, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        return (int[]) regCreateKeyEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key)});
    }

    private static void writeStringValue(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String valueName, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{hkey, toCstr(key), KEY_ALL_ACCESS});
        regSetValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0], toCstr(valueName), toCstr(value)});
        regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[]{handles[0]});
    }

    private static byte[] toCstr(String str) {

        byte[] result = new byte[str.length() + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            result[i] = (byte) str.charAt(i);
        }
        result[str.length()] = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can execute these "REG QUERY" command using **java** code.

Try to execute this from command prompt and execute command from java code.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"

To Search details like productname version etc.. use /v amd "name".

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"

Comment: Refer the URL:- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings

try to execute your "REG QUERY" from this code.

Answer (score -8):

I prefer using [java.util.prefs.Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) class.

A simple example would be

```
// Write Operation
Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
p.put("key","value"); 
// also there are various other methods such as putByteArray(), putDouble() etc.
p.flush();
//Read Operation
Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
String value = p.get("key");
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.